# How to convert NSCFString to an Array

Tags: swift

This is what I received from `userInfo`,

```
AnyHashable("data"): [
  { "number": "1", name: "one" }, 
  { "number": "2", name: "two" }
]
```

This is what I can get using `userInfo["data"]`

```
[
  { "number": "1", name: "one" }, 
  { "number": "2", name: "two" }
]
```

But when I print the type it says NSCFString so I want to convert it to an array so I can loop through it.

I'm new to Swift so an explanation would be very much appreciated. thank you!

Comment: This looks like a JSON string. What you need is to decode it.

Comment: It isn’t at all clear what you are asking. “This is what I received from userInfo”. What does that mean? What userInfo? You say “When I type it is says NSCFString.” What does “when I type it” mean? When you type what? Explain the steps you are following to get data that is in a string format. Where does this data come from?. Is it userInfo attached to some callback like a notification?

Comment: What do you mean “convert it to an array?” If it’s a string do you want to convert it to an array of characters? Or, as Leo suggests, does the string contain JSON data, so you want to deserialize it into objects?

Comment: @DuncanC yes, the userInfo is attached to the notification. What I mean on your your second question is that I used ```print(type(of: userInfo["data"]))``` and it returned the NSCFString

Comment: Then use `JSONSerialization` or `JSONDecoder` on `Data(theString.utf8)`, where `theString`, is `userInfo["data"] as String`

Comment: I want to convert it to an array of objects because I need to loop through it for some validations and I tried to use the JSONDecoder() to decode it but this error appear  "Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to expected argument type 'Data'"

Comment: @Larme It is working now! I've been playing with the ```JSONSerialization``` or ```JSONDecoder``` hoping for it to work but I keep on getting errors. After following your comment it led me to the right path. Thank you and thanks to everyone!